# Recuperar informações passadas em um Bundle

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment

Tenho um Fragment que chama um outro fragment passando informações de login para o outro. 
Faço isso com o seguinte código através do Bundle. Segue o código :

```
ImageView editarBt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.editar);
            editarBt.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    data.putString("nome", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getNome());
                    data.putString("email", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getEmail());
                    data.putString("np", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getNp());
                    data.putString("tipoFunc", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getTipoFunc());
                    data.putInt("id", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getId());
                    Fragment fragment = new adicionar_usuario();
                    fragment.setArguments(data);

                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content,fragment,fragment.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                }
            });
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo capturar esses dados no outro fragmente. Consegui fazer isso com Intent quando tenho activitys, com o seguinte código:

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    if(intent != null){
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle != null){
            int id = bundle.getInt("id");
            String nome = bundle.getString("nome");
            String email = bundle.getString("email");
            String tipoFunc = bundle.getString("tipoFunc");
            String np = bundle.getString("np");

            usuario.setId(id);
            usuario.setNome(nome);
            usuario.setEmail(email);
            usuario.setTipoFunc(tipoFunc);
            usuario.setNp(np);

            nomeEt.setText(usuario.getNome());
            emailEt.setText(usuario.getEmail());
            npEt.setText(usuario.getNp());
            tipoFuncSp.toString();

            senhaEt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            salvarBt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editarUserBt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    }
```

Como transformar esse código para um Fragment? Fazendo com que o campo de usuário carregue com as informações do usuário ao clicar no botão editar.

Está com o seguinte erro:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                   at com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement.adicionar_usuario.onCreateView(adicionar_usuario.java:116)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para recuperar os dados do `bundle`, use o método [`getAguments()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()). Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(...) { 
    .
    .
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        int id = bundle.getInt("id");
    }
```

Comment: @acklay Editei como vc me informou, mas está dando erro. Editei na pergunta.

Comment: Debuga o código cara. Verifique se intent realmente está dando fierente de null, caso contrário não entrará dentro da condição `if(intent != null)`

Comment: o intent está igual null

Comment: @LucasCharles por isso não estava entrando na condição. =D hehehe

Comment: Pois é haha agora estou tentando ver o pq. Quando estou degubando minhas informaçõs estão corretas, mas quando eu passo, elas vão como null para o outro fragmente. `Fragment fragment = new adicionar_usuario();
                    fragment.setArguments(data);

                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content,fragment,fragment.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();`

Comment: @LucasCharles Qual intent? O que você recebe com `getArguments()` é um Bundle. Por outro lado o erro postado na pergunta refere-se ao facto de um EditText ser nulo e não o Bundle. Edite a pergunta e coloque o código do método `onCreateView()`.

Comment: @acklay Muito obrigado!

Comment: @LucasCharles funcionou certinho?! Precisar de mais alguma coisa, de um toque e/ou faça uma pergunta. O pessoal aqui do SO na maioria das vezes gostam de ajudar.

Comment: @acklay funcionou sim :)